# When searching for words in a line from a text file, certain words aren't showing up

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, cpu-word

The following code is searching a text file by line to filter through bad lines and add the good lines to a new file. For some reason, the file is only returning lines with '-', and not responding to any of the other words.

Is there a problem with this code that might cause this to happen? Or is it more likely a problem with the text file?

```
import re
new=open('FilteredData.txt', 'w')
f=open('ClusteredData.txt', 'r')
line = f.readline()

while line:
    reResult = re.search(r'-',line, re.I)
    reResult1 = re.search(r'by', line, re.I)
    reResult2=re.search(r'ft', line, re.I)
    reResult3=re.search(r'feat', line, re.I)
    reResult4=re.search(r'f\.', line, re.I)

    if reResult or reResult1 or reResult2 or reResult3 or reResult4:
        new.write(line)

    line = f.readline()
```

Comment: show your new file

Comment: It won't let me show it because it contains a lot of links, these are tweets ripped from a twitter API.

Comment: Why are you doing 5 different `re` searches? You can make a single regexp that matches all of them `r'-|by|ft|feat|f\.'`

Comment: For error checking, I just never changed it back. I knew I wasn't getting enough results so I split it up to check.

Comment: Try printing each of the `reResultX` values to see what they are.

Comment: Just tried that, nothing other than reResult (the first one) takes a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced a similar problem before due to text encoding issues. The code looks fine to me, I have ran it on a text file without any non-ascii characters, with UTF-8 encoding, and it works. Is there any gibberish in your new text file? If there is, it is likely a problem with the text file itself. Try checking that your text is encoded with the right encoding.

Maybe try running the code on a small subset of the text file and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you this worked, I had it with UTF-16 and I changed it to UTF-8.